# ASCII to 2's complement in Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm working on implementing a function that converts a string of digits in ASCII into its corresponding 64-bit 2’s-complement value.

A register like %rdi will contain the argument char *s which is the the address of the first byte of the string to be converted

The string will be null-terminated. A register like %rsi will contain the argument long *x which is the address where you will place the result of the conversion.

I don't even know where to start. How do I convert ASCII to 2's complement? I've been looking and I found out I should take advantage of 0x0F, how can I use it? Where should I start?

Comment: Please see our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how this site works.  This type of question is not a good fit because it is not a specific programming problem.

Comment: Use MOVSX to produce a signed value from a byte, MOVZX to produce an unsigned value.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an ASCII character to 2's complement you need to `AND` the ASCII number with `0x0F`.
For example: you read ASCII character `7` into `%rsi`. Register `%rdi` holds `0x0F`.

`7` is equivalent to: `0011 0111`.

`0x0F` is equivalent to: `0000 1111`.

The result of `AND`ing the two together results in: `0000 0111` which is `7` in binary.

Hope this helped!